# Does getopts read in command line arguments in some order?

Tags: bash, getopts

Bash manual says

> ```
> getopts optstring name [args]
> ```
>
> When the end of options is encountered, `getopts` exits with a return
>   value greater than zero. `OPTIND` is set to the index of the first
>   non-option argument and `name` is set to `?`.

Does it mean that

- `getopts` only read in options and option arguments, but not arguments which are neither options nor option arguments?
- `getopts` can't work with the case where in the command line, some options are specified after some arguments which are neither options nor option arguments? In other words, does `getopts` require that arguments which are neither options nor option arguments be specified after all the options and option arguments?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried working through the tutorial you linked to earlier? It should answer your questions.

Comment: Yes, unless I miss something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `getopts` is the tool to parse options in the POSIX way (even in `bash`, the GNU shell):

In:

```
cmd -abc -dxx -e yy arg -f -g
```

(with an optspec of `:abcd:e:fg`)

`-f` and `-g` are regular arguments. `getopts` stops at that `arg`.

Generally, you do:

```
while getopts...
  case...esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"
echo Remaining arguments:
[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf ' - %s\n' "$@"
```

If you want to process the options the GNU way, where options are considered after non-option arguments (except when there's a `--` or when POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment), you can use the `util-linux` or busybox implementation of `getopt` instead (with a different API). That one also supports long options. That won't be portable outside of Linux though.

You do something like:

```
parsed_opts=$(getopt -o abcd:e:fg -l long -- "$@") || usage
eval "set -- $parsed_opts"
for o do
  case $o in
    (-[abcfg]) echo "no-arg option: $o"; shift;;
    (--long) echo "long option"; shift;;
    (-[de]) printf '%s\n' "option $o with arg $2"; shift 2;;
    (--) shift; break;;
    (*) echo "never reached";;
  esac
done
echo Remaining args:
[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf ' - %s\n' "$@"
```

Note that their will be some re-ordering in that options and their arguments will be removed from the "remaining args":

```
$ busybox getopt -o abcd:e:fg -l long -- -a foo bar -e x baz --l
 -a -e 'x' --long -- 'foo' 'bar' 'baz'
```